# Views, multiple pagers on same page

Tags: views, paging

I have multiple views with pagers on same page. But all of the pagers using the same GET argument "page", so when user chooses a page in first pager, all of the pagers changing their state to those page. How can I make things work? Drupal 6, Views 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the ID used for the pager: The setting is under the advanced options for the view, in the administration area.